# Deny incoming traffic with docker and ansible iptables

Tags: docker, jenkins, ansible

In a standalone server, I have a docker container running jenkins. I want to write a playbook that allows me (some public ip, let's say it is 107.33.11.111), to connect via 22 and 8080 to the jenkins server on my standalone server, but nobody else. Public traffic is coming on eth0 on my standalone server. I am using [this guide](https://github.com/joelhans/ssdnodes-ansible-provision/blob/master/roles/iptables/tasks/main.yml) to try and make this work.

Here is an example of how I run jenkins:

```
# privileged is needed to allow browser based testing via chrome
- name: Run jenkins container
  command: docker run --privileged -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
```

I then set this firewall rule:

```
- name: Firewall rule - allow port 22/SSH traffic only for me
  iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    in_interface: eth0
    destination_port: 22
    jump: ACCEPT
    protocol: tcp
    source: 107.33.11.111

- name: Firewall rule - allow port 8080 traffic only for me
  iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    in_interface: eth0
    destination_port: 8080
    jump: ACCEPT
    protocol: tcp
    source: 107.33.11.111

- name: Firewall rule - drop any traffic without rule
  iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    jump: DROP
    in_interface: eth0
```

When I execute the above playbook, and run `iptables -L`, my output trims to only:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

When I remove the last rule to drop all traffic, I can observe the entire output, and the ip tables show my ip being permitted for ports 22 and 8080. However, all other traffic coming to eth0 is able to reach those ports as well.

What do I need to do to allow 22 and 8080 only for a specific public address in my ansible playbook?

Comment: What you try to achieve is something on the network level of your server. I think if possible you're better of introducing something like a reverse proxy for this. The reverse proxy's single job is to redirect traffic and it handles whitelists/blacklists mostly out of the box. Have a look into Nginx for example. When you use tools like docker-compose you should be able to create a seperate network which contains only your jenkins server and the nginx instance. Opening port for Nginx then ensures all traffic will flow through there.

Comment: run `iptables -L` ' with sudo

Comment: What system and ansible version are you using? I can't reproduce your behavior with your tasks on Ansible 2.9.7 and iptables 1.8.4.

Comment: @duthils ubuntu 16.04.06 && ansible ansible 2.9.7 && iptables v1.6.0

Comment: @ofirule sudo makes no difference in the output. I only see the trimmed output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your specific use case, you do not need to jump to another chain, but you can set the default policy to `DROP` after allowing 8080 and 22.

Replace the last stanza in your playbook with

```
- name: Firewall rule - drop any traffic without rule
  iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    policy: DROP
```